# How to run query after insert only if a new row was inserted?

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I integrate the following query in MySQL in only one?

```
query1
INSERT INTO table (a, b, c ...) 
SELECT a, b, c ... FROM table
WHERE code = 888

query2
UPDATE table SET a=?,b=?,...
WHERE code = 888
```

Basically I need to execute query2 only if query1 inserted a new row in the table.

Comment: @vSugumar you are wrong, please read more about MySQL, that's possible

Comment: Do you want to create [trigger](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-trigger.html) on after update event?

Comment: get row count of inserted row...if($rows>0) then execute update query

Comment: Why would you change the value immediately after inserting it?

Answer (score 1):

Use a trigger to solve your question. For example:

```
CREATE TRIGGER MyTrigger AFTER INSERT ON table
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    UPDATE table SET a=?,b=?,...
  END;
```

Also you can add condition to check inserted values. Fore more details see [CREATE TRIGGER Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-trigger.html) topic and [examples](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can combine it this way:

```
INSERT INTO table (a, b, c ...) 
SELECT ?, ?, c ... FROM table
WHERE code = 888
```

select data from table 1 and insert it and some constant values into table b

Answer (score -1):

follow below process
i think solved your problem
query1

```
INSERT INTO table (a, b, c ...) 
SELECT a, b, c ... FROM table
WHERE code = 888
$last_id = mysql_insert_id();
```

query2

```
UPDATE table SET a=?,b=?,...
WHERE id= $last_id;
```

Comment: Do not suggest using deprecated `mysql_*` api